# Get stream with RestSharp as it's being streamed from the server

Tags: c#, httpclient, restsharp

My server constantly streaming data and I want to read it on C# app. I found that I can use `RestRequest.ResponseWriter` but it's only called once when the server done streaming. How do I get data as it's coming in? Do I need to use `DownloadDataAsync` method or something else? Or, maybe `RestSharp` cannot do this and I need to switch to `HttpClient`?

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_api");
var request = new RestRequest("get_data");
request.ResponseWriter = (responseStream) =>
{
     var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
     var res = reader.Read();
     Console.WriteLine(res);
     return responseStream;
};
await restClient.DownloadDataAsync(request);
```

Comment: Why it was downvoted? I couldn't find an answer in the internet so I asked here. What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get data from the stream with `RestSharp`, while it's being streamed from the server, as shown below:

```
var restClient = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_api");
var request = new RestRequest("get_data");
var stream = await restClient.DownloadStreamAsync(request);
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
while (true)
{
    var res = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    // Process response
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data streaming is not the main concern of RestSharp from what I understand. You also did not show how the server is treaming data. Assuming you are doing something like this on the server

```
public async Task Get()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    var stream = Response.Body;
    using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync($"Line {i + 1}");
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        await Task.Delay(1000);  // Delay to simulate time-consuming task
    }
}
```

You can get the data chunk on client using HttpClient

```
using var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip })
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44390/")
};
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/stream");
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var buffer = new byte[8192]; // Adjust buffer size if needed
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Though I think it would be best to look into HTTP alternatives like WebSocket or gRPC. SignalR may be a fitting library for your usecase

Comment: I was actually going to use WebSocket once I couldn't make it work with `RestSharp`. But, eventually I managed to do this with `RestSharp` (see my posted answer). I'm still considering changing to WebSocket/gRPC or something similar in the near future.